# SQL query to pull multiple entries with same user_id

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select

I have a table that contains id, created, user_id.

I'm wondering if there is a query that'll return all unique user_ids that have more than one entried created within the last week. I started with:

```
$query = "SELECT distinct user_id FROM task where created >= '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week", strtotime($date))) . " 00:00:00' and created <= '" . $date . " 23:59:99'"
```

This works for returning ALL distinct results, but I need to only grab those that have more than 1 entry in the last week.

Thanks!

Comment: you will need to GROUP BY user_id, week  and use HAVING...

Comment: select the user_id and count within the range with a count > 1 and then select the distinct user id from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id  FROM task
where created >= '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week", strtotime($date))) . " 00:00:00' 
 and created <= '" . $date . " 23:59:99'
 group by user_id
 having count(*) > 1
```